# Why there is still error after i import the org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils? How to resolve them and how to add the import properly?

Tags: java, import

[After i import it stills remain error? Where should I download the the import? How to import?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q8zb2.jpg)

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*; 
import java.lang.*; 
import java.util.Scanner; 
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class Activity {
public static void main1(String[] args) {

    try {
      InputStream is = ReadJsonClass.class.getResourceAsStream(myData.json ); 
      String text = IOUtils.toString(is, "UTF-8") ;
      JSONObject myJsonObject = new JSONObject(text);
      System.out.println(myJsonObject);
    } catch (IOException | JSONException e) {
        System.out.println("Try you have never caught before");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, what's written when you hover the red line on the import ?

Comment: The import org.apache cannot be resolved

Comment: It means that this package is not in the project. If it is an external jar do : ```Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries > Add external JARs```. If it's not, and depending on the type of project (Maven for exemple) check your dependencies to see if the packages have been installed.

Answer (score 0):

myData.json must be in double quotes.